# Libgdx Actions => gradually move Actor from point A to point B

Tags: libgdx

I want to gradually animate my Actor. I added this Action to move Actor from point A to point B.

```
addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.moveBy(1, 1), Actions.moveTo(posX, posY)));
```

Also tried this (moveTo in 10 seconds):

```
addAction(Actions.moveTo(posX, posY, 10)));
```

But Actor moves too fast. What's wrong?

Comment: You can also use the [Universal Tween Engine](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/universal-tween-engine) for this. Works also for sprites and has many functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second form:

```
addAction(Actions.moveTo(posX, posY, 10)));
```

should move your actor to posX, posY over the course of 10 seconds.

The first form will move the actor 1-step in x and y, and after that completes move the actor immediately to posX, posY.  `Actions.sequence` runs the given actions one after the other, they do not modify each other.

How (and where) are you calling `act()` on the stage?  That is what determines how much to update an `Actor` in a frame, so if you call it multiple times per frame or pass the wrong value, the actions will pass too quickly.

Answer (score 5):

Just because your answer was top when I searched 'Libgdx Move to Point' I will post a solution here.

Here is a solution, not specifically for Actors:

**Define you Vector2 variables in the class, these will be used for object position:**

```
protected Vector2 v2Position;
protected Vector2 v2Velocity;
```

**The position is set in the constructor or wherever else. To get the Velocity of the object and move it to the given point:**

```
public void setVelocity (float toX, float toY) {

// The .set() is setting the distance from the starting position to end position
v2Velocity.set(toX - v2Position.x, toY - v2Position.y);
v2Velocity.nor(); // Normalizes the value to be used

v2Velocity.x *= speed;  // Set speed of the object
v2Velocity.y *= speed;
}
```

**Now just add the Velocity to the Position and the object will move to the point given**

```
@Override public void update() {
    v2Position.add (v2Velocity);    // Update position
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me in the right direction. In the update method I did `v2Position.lerp(v2Velocity);` because I needed the object to move to and stop at a specific position.